# Save HTML table to CSV, then send to server and save it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, csv, html-table

I have an HTML table that I want to save as a CSV on my server when a button is clicked.

How can I do this?

Overview:

1. Take HTML table and convert it to a CSV (Javascript).
2. Send CSV to server (Javascript using AJAX to Rails)
3. Have server do something with the file (Rails).

My best option is to convert the HTML table to a CSV string (http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) using this plugin `function exportTableToCSV($table, filename)`, send that with ajax to rails, then try to pass that off as a "csv file". Am I forgetting anything about why this won't work? Or any more obvious way?